# Android is confusing the functions of 3 different buttons

Tags: java, android, button, android-activity

I'm currently making an app that will play some music.

There will be multiple activities, one for each song. There are usually 3 buttons per screen: One to play/pause the music, one for going to the previous page, and one for going to the next page.

Currently, Android is confused about which buttons are supposed to do what. When I click on the 'Play Music' button, the app attempts to take me to the next screen. When I click on the 'Next Page' button, it brings me to the previous page. When I click on the 'Last Page' button, it plays/pauses the song.

This is my java code for the relevant activity.

```
package net.jacksonhamilton.calmingmusic;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Rush extends Activity {

    Button btnRush, btnRushtoCivil, btnRushtoNeil;
    MediaPlayer tomsawyer;
    int playing;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rush);
        btnRush = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRush);
        btnRushtoCivil = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRushtoCivil);
        btnRushtoNeil = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRushtoNeil);
        btnRush.setOnClickListener(btRush);
        btnRushtoCivil.setOnClickListener(btRushtoCivil);
        btnRushtoNeil.setOnClickListener(btRushtoNeil);
        tomsawyer = new MediaPlayer();
        tomsawyer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tomsawyer);
        playing = 0;

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    Button.OnClickListener btRush = new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (playing) {
                case 0:
                tomsawyer.start();
                playing = 1;
                btnRush.setText("Pause 'Tom Sawyer', by Rush");
                break;
                case 1:
                tomsawyer.pause();
                playing = 0;
                btnRush.setText("Play 'Tom Sawyer', by Rush");
                break;
            }
        }
    };
    Button.OnClickListener btRushtoCivil = new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tomsawyer.stop();
            startActivity(new Intent(Rush.this, Splash.class));
        }

    };
    Button.OnClickListener btRushtoNeil = new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tomsawyer.stop();
            startActivity(new Intent(Rush.this, Neilyoung.class));
        }

    };
}
```

I've checked the IDs in the XML layout file, both graphically and in code. All buttons are assigned the proper IDs and the proper string value (for the text on the buttons).

I have the app set to require SDK15 as the minimum, and it is targeted to SDK19. It is also compiling with SDK19.

If it matters, I am developing the app in Eclipse Mars.

If you'd like to see the app for reference, [here is a picture of the Activity.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNMo1.png)

Comment: possibly just requires a clean of the project. (also, unrelated, but eclipse is deprecated for android dev)

Comment: I would be using Android Studio, but the course I'm taking uses a textbook that uses Eclipse. It's easier to do when I am able to do a direct comparison.

Comment: Code does not change, only IDE

Answer (score 0):

You must have messed something up in the layout file, or you may be running some old version of the app. It sometimes happens in Eclipse that it does not rebuild the app but starts a last built version instead. Try deleting the app from the device/emulator, restarting the emulator, cleaning project or restarting IDE.